# Single command in python to install relevant modules from a package.json like file

Tags: python, pip

In node.js, one can do `npm update --production` during deployment and all the relevant node.js modules will be installed as long as the right package.json is in place.

Is there a python equivalent command line for easy deployment? Can pip do the same thing as npm?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

yes there is an command for doing that , once you want to deploy you can generate the package file using the following command:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

and whenever you want to install the packages from same file use:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

you can find more info about freeze [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/)

Comment: This halts the installation if one of the library in the requirement.txt fails to install. If you want to continue installation irrespective of some libraries failing then try `cat req.txt | xargs -L 1 pip install`

Answer (score 24):

**TLDR;** `poetry` would be equivalent to `npm`.

I would use **pipenv** instead of pip. pipenv automatically generate Pipfile and Pipfile.lock that is far superior to requirements.txt

install pipenv and setting it for your project

```
pip install --user pipenv

cd yourproject
pipenv install package1 package2 ...
```

to install packages from Pipfile is as simple as

```
pipenv install
```

Read more: https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/

**Update:** hello to **poetry**

I have recently moved from pipenv to poetry because poetry has everything pipenv offers and much more. It is end-to-end, as it includes building and publishing of your project to pypi.

installing poetry

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdispater/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python
```

and set .poetry/bin in your path.

```
poetry new yourproject
cd yourproject
poetry add packagename
```

Like pipenv this generate pyproject.toml file that context all your requirements. Like Pipenv, to install your depence

```
poetry install
```

See more: https://poetry.eustace.io/docs/

See [Python packaging war: Pipenv vs. Poetry](https://frostming.com/2018/05-15/pipenv-vs-poetry) for short review of these awesome packages

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! `pipenv` (or `poetry` if your prefer) is the equivalent of `npm`, `yarn`, `composer` etc. `pip` alone cannot do the same.

Comment: is conda / anaconda is the same alternative for poetry and pipenv?

Comment: Yes it is. For data scientists new to Python, I would recommend conda.

Answer (score 6):

You can do a

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

In the local machine. And in the server,

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This installs all the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put your packages in a simple text file `requirements.txt`, e.g. (version numbers are optional)

```
SQLAlchemy==1.0.4
requests==2.4.3
```

and then do `pip install -r requirements.txt`