# No translation file found for domain 'django'

Tags: python, django

Environment :

- python 2.7.10
- django 1.8.6(copied from site-package folder)

I copied the django distribute into my project folder.

Thinking it will work well

It works perfectly in one of my machine, but throw an error below in another one

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "cmdb_lib/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "cmdb_lib/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "cmdb_lib/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "cmdb_lib/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "cmdb_lib/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "cmdb_lib/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    translation.activate(saved_locale)
  File "cmdb_lib/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 146, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "cmdb_lib/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 222, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "cmdb_lib/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 206, in translation
    _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
  File "cmdb_lib/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 115, in __init__
    self._init_translation_catalog()
  File "cmdb_lib/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 153, in _init_translation_catalog
    translation = self._new_gnu_trans(localedir, use_null_fallback)
  File "cmdb_lib/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 136, in _new_gnu_trans
    fallback=use_null_fallback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 472, in translation
    raise IOError(ENOENT, 'No translation file found for domain', domain)
IOError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: u'django'
```

But in my `settings.py` I set `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'` as default!

How could this throw an error?

I tried to `pip install django`, problem solved ,but I still want to include the django package in my project.

How can I achieve  this?

Comment: Why do you want to include the django package? Reasons will help us help you

Comment: `I copied the django distribute into my project folder` - why did you do this?

Comment: I installed django through ``pip install django==1.8.6`` ,and copied the site-package/django into my project's folder.

Comment: I wanted to release my project in a place which only python environment is provided ,no other python package like django could be installed, so I have to include the django package

Comment: Just copying all the dependencies into project folder is not a solution that you are looking for. The best way is to do a pip freeze and have the requirements file in the project folder. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751214/single-command-in-python-to-install-relevant-modules-from-a-package-json-like-fi/33751278#33751278

Comment: `I wanted to release my project in a place which only python environment is provided, no other python package like django could be installed,` What kind of place is that?

Comment: I think I got the solution , my ``.gitignore``file ignored the .mo file , I added it and everything 's OK now

Comment: @AswinMurugesh Embedded or air-gapped systems with no ability to download dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the solution , my `.gitignore`file ignored the .mo file , I added it and everything 's OK now

If you are using git, check your `.gitignore` file and comment`*.mo`

add the missing `.mo`file ,and things will be good