# Fail with django app on azure

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to develop and deploy django app on azure web apps.
While following the [tutorial on azure website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app), after cloning the basic project to my local machine (using git) and creating the virtual environment, I'm trying to run the `createsuperuser` commend, and getting this error:

```
C:\Users\tutzy\Desktop\newtest\amir1>env\scripts\python manage.py createsuperuser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\tutzy\Desktop\newtest\amir1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\tutzy\Desktop\newtest\amir1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\tutzy\Desktop\newtest\amir1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\tutzy\Desktop\newtest\amir1\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 52, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\tutzy\Desktop\newtest\amir1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 413, in execute
    translation.activate(saved_locale)
  File "C:\Users\tutzy\Desktop\newtest\amir1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 154, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "C:\Users\tutzy\Desktop\newtest\amir1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 216, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "C:\Users\tutzy\Desktop\newtest\amir1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 205, in translation
    _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
  File "C:\Users\tutzy\Desktop\newtest\amir1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 118, in __init__
    raise IOError("No translation files found for default language %s." % settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
IOError: No translation files found for default language en-us.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your issue was similar with the other SO thread [No translation file found for domain 'django'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802686/no-translation-file-found-for-domain-django) if you clone the Azure offical sample for Django like [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-python-get-started). There is a  `*.mo` line at the 49th line of [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-python-get-started/blob/master/.gitignore#L49) file. Please try to add the missing `.mo` file and do the `createsupersuer` operation again.

Hope it helps.